# DirectX C++ Disc animation

Tags: c++, animation, directx, sprite

So here is my problem I need a sprite to move at specific locations: -

When the bottom of the sprite is 600 pixels from the top of the screen change the vertical direction of motion from down-screen to up-screen.

When the right-edge of the sprite is 200 pixels from the left of the screen change the horizontal direction of motion from right-to-left, to left-to-right

When the top edge of the sprite is 400 pixels from the top of the screen change the vertical motion from up-screen to down-screen.

When the left edge of the sprite is 0 pixels from the left side of the screen change the horizontal direction of motion from right-to-left to left-to-right.

So here is what i have got its currently using the sides of the screen, any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
void Disc::Update(double totalTime, double timeDelta)
{
// function for calculating displacement is time * velocity
// timeDelta is how much time has passed since the last update call
DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2 toMove = this->discVelocity * timeDelta;

this->spritePosition = this->spritePosition + toMove;

if (this->spritePosition.x >= (screenWidth - this->spriteWidth))
{
    // reverse velocity ( set negative)
    this->discVelocity.x = this->discVelocity.x * -1;
    //this->spriteEffect =       D  DirectX::SpriteEffects::SpriteEffects_FlipHorizontally;
}
else if (this->spritePosition.x < 0)
{
    // reverse velocity
    this->discVelocity.x = this->discVelocity.x * -1;
    //this->spriteEffect = DirectX::SpriteEffects::SpriteEffects_None;
}
else if (this->spritePosition.y >= screenHeight - 100)
{
    this->discVelocity.y = this->discVelocity.y * -1;
}
else if (this->spritePosition.y <= 0)
{
    this->discVelocity.y = this->discVelocity.y * -1;
}
}
```

Comment: So where do you need help? Only some arithmetic seems to be required here.

Comment: I don't need screen width, so could declaring a new position work. I have an idea of how to change it but not sure which bits to correct.